# What is wrong with my logic for extracting the inner text of table cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, algorithm, dom

I'm trying to make a procedure that works like the following:

```
<tbody id="slide-table-body">
   <tr>
        <td>
             pic1.jpg
        </td>
        <td>
             pic2.jpg
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>
             pic3.jpg
        </td>
        <td>
             pic4.jpg
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>
             pic5.jpg
        </td>
        <td>
             pic6.jpg
        </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

------------------------------------->

```
[ { assetPreviewUrl: "pic1.jpg", assetUrl: "pic2.jpg" }, 
  { assetPreviewUrl: "pic3.jpg", assetUrl: "pic4.jpg" }, 
  { assetPreviewUrl: "pic5.jpg", assetUrl: "pic6.jpg" } ]
```

I could describe in more rigorous terms, but I think you get the idea: basically, it parses inner text of the cells and stores the results as JSON.

My function to run the procedure is the following, which doesn't work.

```
parseSlides = function ( )
{
    var slidesArr = [];
    $('#slide-table-body').children().each(function() { // each row
        slidesArr.push(
            {
               assetPreviewUrl : $(this).first().text(), // first cell's text 
               assetUrl        : $(this).last().text() // second/last cell's text
            }
        );           
    });
    return slidesArr; 
}
```

Output is instead like

```
[ { assetPreviewUrl: "pic1.jpgpic2.jpg", assetUrl: "pic1.jpgpic2.jpg" }, 
  { assetPreviewUrl: "pic3.jpgpic4.jpg", assetUrl: "pic3.jpgpic4.jpg" }, 
  { assetPreviewUrl: "pic5.jpgpic6.jpg", assetUrl: "pic5.jpgpic6.jpg" } ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Thanks for your answers. I'm going to randomly decide who to choose as best answer:

```
var answerers = [ "BG101", "Skylord123", "Igor" ];
console.log(answerers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answerers.length)]); // printed "Skylord123"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `first()` and `last()` JQuery functions I would instead use `children('td:first')` and `children('td:last')`.

When you run `first()` on `this` you are grabbing the first item in the list which is `this` in this case. You are not getting the first child element. Using the `children()` function with a selector will grab you the child elements from `this`.

I tested this and it worked. So revise your code to this:

```
parseSlides = function ( )
{
    var slidesArr = [];
    $('#slide-table-body').children().each(function() { // each row
        slidesArr.push(
            {
               assetPreviewUrl : $(this).children('td:first').text(), // first cell's text 
               assetUrl        : $(this).children('td:last').text() // second/last cell's text
            }
        );           
    });
    return slidesArr; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.first - Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

**NOT**

get the first child element.

With `$(this).first().text()` and `$(this).last().text()` you get `innerText` of the row both times.

Comment: In the case he is doing, calling first() on $(this) will return the first element in the list, which is not what he wants. He wants the first and last child elements.

Comment: @Skylord123 - that's what I said.

Comment: ah, I missed it. Sorry. :)

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: @epascarello - the OP already knows about `children` function.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
parseSlides = function ( )
{
    var slidesArr = [];
    $('#slide-table-body').children().each(function() { // each row
        slidesArr.push(
            {
               assetPreviewUrl : $(this).children().first().text(), // first cell's text 
               assetUrl        : $(this).children().last().text() // second/last cell's text
            }
        );           
    });
    return slidesArr; 
}
```